# How to display data in a json file with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to do as the title suggested. The problem is, my browser is not displaying anything from the json file. It should be pretty straight away but I can't seem to know what went wrong.

Here is my app.controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.display = data;
    }); 
});
```

And I have a separate html file

```
<html ng-app ="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <script type='text/javascript' src="bower_components/angular/angular.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="app/app.controller.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <h2> Message Display  </h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Title </th>
                    <th> abstract </th>
                    <th> source </th>
                    <th> publihsed time </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat = "item in display">
                    <td> {{item.title}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.abstract}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.source}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.publish_time}} </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

And I made sure that each file is in the correct directory. But right not the browser is only displaying the  tag
[image]

Screenshot of json structure[image]

I run the code using $node server.js 
this is the code for server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: can you post your json structure? also it is possible that your view is rendered sooner than the response comes back

Comment: are you getting errors? what doe the page look like?

Comment: I am not getting errors. I just don't get the information in the json file that I am supposed to display

Comment: even after i set the data in "data in display" to something else it still doesn't print anything on the browser

Comment: not data.title but display.title

Comment: display.title doesn't work

Comment: You may need to convert your data.json to UTF-8, I faced this issue before when parsing json data. You can use Notepad++ to convert.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to re-order your scripts so they load in the order below. So that your `app controller` script loads after the `Angular library`, this is most likely the issue. Since Angular doesn't load before you try using it to make the ajax request to you `json.data`.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="bower_components/angular/angular.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="app/app.controller.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Secondlu in you `app controller` script you need to name you `ng-app` the same thing as your `module` variable like this:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            type:"GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                "Accept-Charset":"charset=utf-8"
            },
            dataType:"json",
            url:"data.json",
        }).then(function success(response){
            $scope.display =response.data;
    });
});
```

These two changes should fix your issue.

**Optional**

You may also consider moving your `ng-repeat` into a `<tbody>` element like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in display">
    <tr>
      <td> {{data.title}} </td>
      <td> {{data.abstract}} </td>
      <td> {{data.source}} </td>
      <td> {{data.publish_time}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: it still doesn't solve the problem. Nothing is displayed. However, I am running directly from server.js. Is it possible that it is causing the problem? i will include it in the question.

Comment: i added the second change as well, but my browser still doesn't display the data I want from the json file.

Comment: I forgot to include the second line of you app.controller.js script after the changes you should be able to run it with out Node.js, you should be able to run it directly in a browser locally on your computer

Comment: yes I changed the second line to myApp as well, but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: do you get any errors in your console? press [F12] button and reload page. also what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome. I also tried firefox but nothing gets displayed. i don't get any errors. it is just not showing anything

Comment: try adding this to the head of your html document `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: added and still displaying nothing

Comment: I've changed the ajax call to force utf-8 see if you have better luck now

Comment: haha no. I have texts I write in html such as "message display" but the real data i want is from the json file, which doesn't get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code something like below. [here is my working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yAOhvBl9Hwgz6bBPDefT?p=preview)

```
app.service('dataService',function($http){

  this.getdata = function(){
      return $http.get('data.json');

  };

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,dataService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.display =[];

  dataService.getdata()
  .then(function(repsonse){
     $scope.display =repsonse.data;

  });

});
```

Comment: i still can't display the data from json

Comment: put a breakpoint int browser on the line $scope.display=response.data and let me know the value which you see there

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working plunker code.